# Ad distribution problem: an optimal solution?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm asked to find a 2 approximate solution to this problem:

You’re consulting for an e-commerce site that receives a large number
of visitors each day. For each visitor i, where i € {1, 2 ..... n}, the site
has assigned a value v[i], representing the expected revenue that can be
obtained from this customer.

Each visitor i is shown one of m possible ads A1, A2 ..... Am as they
enter the site. The site wants a selection of one ad for each customer so
that each ad is seen, overall, by a set of customers of reasonably large
total weight.

Thus, given a selection of one ad for each customer, we will
define the *spread* of this selection to be the minimum, over j = 1, 2 ..... m,
of the total weight of all customers who were shown ad Aj.

Example: Suppose there are six customers with values 3, 4, 12, 2, 4, 6, and
there are m = 3 ads. Then, in this instance, one could achieve a spread of
9 by showing ad A1 to customers 1, 2, 4, ad A2 to customer 3, and ad A3 to
customers 5 and 6.

The ultimate goal is to find a selection of an ad for each customer
that *maximizes* the spread.

Unfortunately, this optimization problem
is NP-hard (you don’t have to prove this).

So instead give a polynomial-time algorithm that approximates the maximum spread within a factor of 2.

The solution I found is the following:

```
Order visitors values in descending order

Add the next visitor value (i.e. assign the visitor) to 
the Ad with the current lowest total value
Repeat
```

This solution actually seems to always find the optimal solution, or I simply can't find a counterexample.
Can you find it? Is this a non-polinomial solution and I just can't see it?

Comment: Some information is missing. Just assign one ad to the minimum value customer and split the rest among the others. By spread did you mean max-min? The usage of spread makes more sense in that case... And 'reasonably large total weight' is not precise enough.

Comment: That is exactly what os written in my textbook. Yes By spread it means max-min.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: Wait sorry I was wrong. The spread is the minimum value and you have to maximize it, as it clearly say: "The ultimate goal is to find a selection of an ad for each customer that maximizes the spread.".

Comment: Ok. That makes more sense then! Funny how one misses whole sentences.

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
v = [7, 6, 5, 3, 3]
m = 2
```

The optimal solution is:

```
A1: 6 + 3 + 3 = 12
A2: 5 + 7 = 12
```

Your solution gives:

```
A1: 7 + 3 + 3 = 13
A2: 6 + 5 = 11
```

Comment: thank you so much!! I tried a lot of different cases but couldn't come up with one not working! Now I can finally start to prove it's 2-approximate :D